# Message Broker 6.1 sleep exception

Tags: sleep, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to add a simple `sleep` function to extend the base ESQL API.

Java implementation:

```
public static void sleep(long millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

ESQL reference:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sleep(IN millis INT)
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    EXTERNAL NAME "com.mypackage.Util.sleep";
```

This is the error trace:

```
(0x01000000:Name     ):RecoverableException = (
        (0x03000000:NameValue):File     = '/build/S610_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbRdl/ImbRdlExternalJava.cpp' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Line     = 1102 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Function = 'ESQL2JavaMethodResolver::decodeReturnStatus' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Type     = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Name     = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Label    = '' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Catalog  = 'BIPv610' (CHARACTER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Severity = 3 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Number   = 2946 (INTEGER)
        (0x03000000:NameValue):Text     = 'The Java method could not be found' (CHARACTER)
        (0x01000000:Name     ):Insert   = (
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Type = 5 (INTEGER)
          (0x03000000:NameValue):Text = 'com.mypackage.Util.sleep' (CHARACTER)
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! For future reference:

The problem was in the method signature check that wants the wrapper type.
In this case `Long` instead of `long`.

```
public static void sleep(Long millis) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```